# Android Moto X 4.2.2 Camera FaceDetectionListener onFaceDetection() never called

Tags: android, camera, face-detection

I have an app using the API level 14 [Camera.FaceDetectionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.FaceDetectionListener.html) in conjunction with Camera.startPreview(), Camera.startFaceDetection(), and Camera.setFaceDetectionListener() after checking [Camera.Parameters.getMaxNumDetectedFaces()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getMaxNumDetectedFaces%28%29).

On the Moto X running 4.2.2, getMaxNumDetectedFaces() returns 5, but onFaceDetection() is never called.

Testing on the HTC One running 4.4.2, everything works as expected (and getMaxNumDetectedFaces() returns 16).

Are there any other checks I could perform to make sure face detection is available on the device?  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on my Sony Xperia M, but the built-in camera app seems to be able to do it fine.